# POST file using request, gridfs-stream and multer

Tags: node.js, request, multer, gridfs-stream

In my node.js-application, I need to read data from a MongoDB with GridFS and upload it to another server via `POST` request, I am using the modules `gridfs-stream`, `request` and `multer`.
According to [the `request` docs](https://github.com/request/request#forms) I can simply add a stream for `multipart/form-data`, so I'm doing this:

```
var fileUuid = "myFilename";

var options = {
    url: "url.to/my/target/",
    method: "POST",
    header: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
    formData: {
        filedata: gfs.createReadStream({filename: fileUuid})
    }
}

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("[" + getDateTime() + "] Error replicating file:");
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }

    console.log('statusCode: ', response && response.statusCode); 
    console.log('body: ', body);
});
```

On my receiving server, I have the following code:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: './tmp_upload/' })

app.post('/my/target', upload.single('filedata'), function(req, res) {
    console.log('['+getDateTime()+'] Request received');
}
```

But whenever I am executing the request, I get the following error on my sending server:

```
[2019:07:26:16:52:00] Error replicating file:
Error: write ECONNRESET
```

and this on my receiving server:

```
Error: Unexpected end of multipart data
    at c:\Users\...\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:62:28
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Can anybody please give me a hint how to `POST` my file from one server to another?

**EDIT:**
The issue seems to be the `gfs.createReadStream({filename: fileUuid})` type of stream... When I write the file to the filesystem first and instead put an `fs.createReadStream(...)` into the form as formData, then it works.
But is there an option to direct the stream directly into the formData, without having to write it to disk first?

Comment: did you get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up working with a temporary file that I read from the database, write it to disk and create a new `readStream` that I then put into the request. After the request was successful, I delete the temporary file from my disk and continue with my code:

```
var fsstreamwrite = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp/" + myFile);
var readstream = gfs.createReadStream( {filename: myFile} );
readstream.pipe(fsstreamwrite);
readstream.on("close", function () {
    console.log("File read successfully from database");

    var options = {
        url: "url.to/my/target/",
        method: "POST",
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        formData: {
            "filedata": fs.createReadStream('./tmp/' + myFile)
        }
    }

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            // error handling
            return;
        }

        // delete temporary file
        fs.unlinkSync('./tmp/' + myFile)

        // continue with my stuff...

    });                                    

});
```